# When is app published on facebook?

Tags: android, ios, facebook

So when is an app published on facebook? Is it simply just when sandbox mode is disabled or is there something else you gotta do?

The thing is I'd like some developers to have access to the app without publishing it so everyone can find it on facebook.

Comment: I really don't get what you're trying to do. Do you want that your android/iOS app is published on facebook for download automatically (not to say magically)?

Comment: No I mean when you register a facebook app under facebook developer console. In there you have the options of having the app in sandbox mode or not. This app can be android, iOS, web etc.

Comment: See step 1: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/build/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to be Facebook friends with your developers, you can add their email addresses instead of their names in the Add Developers section of the app dashboard.  That should be a valid workaround for adding developers for your app without being friends on Facebook.

Answer (score 1):

> The thing is I'd like some developers to have access to the app without publishing it so everyone can find it on facebook.

Then keep it in Sandbox mode, and add those developers as admins or test users to your app, from inside the app dashboard.

Comment: Ye I know that possibility, but then I need to add them as friends on facebook... Which is quite bothersome as you don't have ALL your contacts as friends on facebook. Just wondering if there was a workaround.